# Set timestamps on a pivot model with Bookshelf.js

Tags: node.js, orm, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I've got two Bookshelf models in a many-to-many relationship and I'd like to have timestamps updated when I'm attaching or detaching some relations.

Here's my models:

```
var Video = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'video',

  program: function(){
    return this.belongsToMany(Bookshelf.model('Program'), 'programvideo', 'videoId', 'programId');
  }
});
var Program = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'program',

  videos: function(){
    return this.belongsToMany(Bookshelf.model('Video'), 'programvideo', 'programId', 'videoId');
  }
});
```

Everything works fine when I'm using

```
prgm.videos().attach(videos);
```

But is there any way to add timestamps to this relation? Do I need to define a pivot model in Bookshelf?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could easily make a pivot model, create in migrations `timestamps` and  enable timestamps in the model, and everything would work seamless!

However, if you'd like to solve this without additional model, you have to define firstly `withPivot` in models, e.g.:

```
var Stations = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'stations',
    stationsRoutes: function() {
        return this.belongsToMany(Routes, 'stations_routes').withPivot('time');
    }
});

var Routes = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'routes',
    stationsRoutes: function() {
        return this.belongsToMany(Stations, 'stations_routes').withPivot('time');
    }
});
```

Then, each time when you attach data, you have to call `updatePivot`, e.g.:

```
router.get('/updatePivot/:id', function(req, res) {
    new Routes({
        'id': req.params.id
    }).fetch({
        withRelated: ['stationsRoutes']
    }).then(function(result) {

        result.stationsRoutes().attach({
            station_id: 3
        }).then(function() {

            result.stationsRoutes().updatePivot({
                'time': '09:09'
            }/*, {
                query: function(qb) {
                    qb.where({
                        'id': 8
                    });
                }
            }*/).then(function() {
                result.load('stationsRoutes').then(function(result_reloaded){
                    res.json(result_reloaded);
                });
            });

        });

    });
});
```

I've commented the piece of code where you can filter a specific row in the junction table that gets updated (if left out, all corresponding rows get updated).

Hope this helps!